# The problem is I can not connect to the internet unless I turn off the wired connection?

Tags: internet

My issue is updating to 20.04 my system crashed.  I did a clean install.  Previous ubuntu 19 no issues.    My issue is the WIFI connection works fine for internet.  My wired connection is fine I can get an ip from my router no problem.  The problem is I can not connect to the internet unless I turn off the wired connection? I am an old guy using this as a media server.  That said I've always hacked my way through

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1306242/edit) to show us the complete output of `ip addr` when the wired connection is active, and also when the wireless connection is active.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the command and output of `ip route`.

Comment: A release upgrade is **not** a clean install.  Ubuntu 19.04 went EOL in January 2020 and Ubuntu 19.10 went EOL on July 17, 2020.  You missed the upgrade window, so I suggest that you actually perform clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 from installation media.  If you are not prepared to upgrade your release promptly every six months for standard releases, you might want to stick with LTS releases since they are supported  for 5 years from release (3 years in the case of flavors other than GNOME).

Comment: john@UBU:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0f0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0f0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.12 metric 100

Comment: after turning off wired and enabling wifi so I can get on internet

default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.26 metric 600